# pass arguments to function from one unit to another in testcomplete and how to call it

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

i am facing a vb script run time error saying "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". 

`'useunit 
sub in unita
call unita.testsub(param1,param2)
end sub`

`'sub in unitb
sub testsub(param1,param2)
.....
end sub`

Comment: What are `unita` and `unitb`? Are they classes, objects, modules?

Comment: they are script units within testcomplete containing functions and procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After USEUNIT you need to specify the name of the unit whose functions you will use in this unit. So, change your code in the following way:

**unita**

```
'USEUNIT unitb
sub main
  dim param1
  dim param2
  param1="Test"
  param2="Complete"
  call unitb.testsub(param1,param2)
end sub
```

**unitb**

```
sub testsub(param1,param2)
  Log.Message(param1 & param2)
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I **believe** that

```
call unita.testsub(param1,param2)
```

should be

```
call unitb.testsub(param1,param2)
```

Comment: implemented  call unitb.testsub(param1,param2) .. still the same error

Answer (score 0):

i found this from the oficial forums 

Execute "Call UnitName.SubWithParams(1, ""string"", True)" ' Using syntax with the Call keyword and parentheses

Execute "UnitName.SubWithParams 1, ""string"", True"       ' Syntax without the Call keyword and parentheses

res = Eval("UnitName.FunctionWithParams(1, ""string"", True)")

' Inserting parameter values dynamically

strFunctionCall = aqString.Format("UnitName.FunctionWithParams(%d, ""%s"", %s)", 42, "string", CStr(True))

res = Eval(strFunctionCall)

but still donot know how exactly should we pass the parameters